# Should I display the 2FA secret only once or it can be always available?

Tags: authentication, multi-factor

A logged-in user enables 2FA for his account and a QR code with the secret is displayed.

Is it correct to display the same QR code again when the user visits the 2FA settings page after some time? Or the QR code should be displayed only once?

If I don't show it again:

- it seems more secure apparently
- but the user can disable and enable 2FA again and the effect is the same
- the user cannot add the same code to a new devices

If I show it again:

- the user has more time to scan it (e.g. if they accidentally close the page)
- can add it to multiple devices

What are the best practices?

Should I display it only once or make it always available if the user is signed in?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what risks are acceptable to you.

Since you allow users to disable 2FA, you tolerate high risks that their accounts can be compromised. Since you tolerate high risks, you can decide based on user experience. In your case it means, you can generate initialization code only once and show it every time user want to initialize OTP, no matter on what device.

There can be cases when risk tolerance is lower. For instance, company policy can require 2FA for all users, they cannot disable it, and it can require that each device uses a separate OTP. In such case displaying the QR code again will not be needed. For each new devices youl will generate a new QR code.

The even lower risk tolerance may require that user has exactly one device for OTP. This reduces the risk that user shares account with other person, or that user loses one of devices, but does not report it, so that this device can be used by somebody else. In such case also showing the QR code more than once is not needed.